# In a box which has balls numbered 1..100 , 5 balls are drawn.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

$X$- random variable that represents the largest number of the 5 drawn. Find the distribution of $X$.

Now, it seems that this random variable is of discrete type. What I have trouble it defining it in mathematical, formal terms because of it's random nature, I honestly come at a road block as to how.. Any thoughts on how I would go about doing this ?

Comment: Do you put back the balls or not.

Comment: Nope, no put backs is the rule

Comment: But for curiosities sake, i'd be interested as to see the result of both predicaments..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- $P(X=5)=\dfrac{\binom{4}{4}}{\binom{100}{5}}$
- $P(X=6)=\dfrac{\binom{5}{4}}{\binom{100}{5}}$
- $P(X=7)=\dfrac{\binom{6}{4}}{\binom{100}{5}}$
- $\dots$

---

And in general:

$$\forall{n\in[5,100]}:P(X=n)=\dfrac{\binom{n-1}{4}}{\binom{100}{5}}$$

---

In words:

Take ball #$n$, and choose another $4$ balls out of balls #$1,\dots,n-1$.

Comment: Can you check out my confusions with this problem too, that is if you have the time?http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1295781/in-a-box-there-are-m-1-balls-numbered-1-m-2-numbered-2-m-n

Comment: @BozoVulicevic: I added a short literal description at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: Quite well, this I understand now..

Answer (score 2):

Count how many ways $n$ can be the largest number.
If you replace the balls, there are $n^5$ ways they can be $\leq n$, minus $(n-1)^5$ ways they are all less than $n$.
If you don't replace the balls, there are $n-1\choose4$ ways that the largest is $n$.

Comment: Can you maybe , give this problem a look, if you have time: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1295781/in-a-box-there-are-m-1-balls-numbered-1-m-2-numbered-2-m-n